# Software to make a flyover video from a GPX log?

Tags: video, gps

I m trying to make a video similar to this (at 53 seconds): https://youtu.be/OEU5BCZV6Sc?t=53 from GPX logs we have from our drone. Google Earth Pro software doesn't allow nearly enough customization, but I'm new to all of this and haven't been able to find what I should use. Paid software is fine as well. Thank you!